# shortest Python solution for creating list from csv string

Tags: python

given a string like this:

```
data ="\n
random stuff\n
a,1\n
b,2\n
c,3\n
...
"
```

I want to create a list from this string using only the lines with a comma. I know I can create a list using the following code:

```
l = [line for line in csv.reader(data.split('\n'))]
```

This will give me [[],['some stuff'],['a',1]...]

but what I **really** want is something like this:

```
#this code is wrong
l = [line if len(line)>1 for line in csv.reader(data.split('\n')]
```

to get a list like this: `[['a',1],['b',2]...]`

I'm mainly looking for the shortest possible solution to do this since I know how to do it the hard way (by iterating through the list `[[],['some stuff'],['a',1]...]` and removing elements from it).

Thanks,

Comment: Shortest isn't always the best...

Comment: @MaximeLorant I agree, I just want to see how to write it as concise as possible.

Comment: @Eric Chen You state you want [[str, int], [str, int]..] as output, but you have accepted a solution giving [[str, str], [str, str]..]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[line for line in csv.reader(data.split('\n')) if len(line) > 1]
```

This is exactly your logic, just put in the right syntax, with the `if` at the end. This will give you the result you wanted:

```
>>> data ="\n random stuff\na,1\nb,2\nc,3\n ... "
>>> [line for line in csv.reader(data.split('\n')) if len(line) > 1]
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

**UPDATE**

If you really want the second elements in the arrays to be parsed as integers, you could write like this:

```
>>> [[x[0], int(x[1])] for x in csv.reader(data.split('\n')) if len(x) > 1]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Comment: Why are we testing `len(line)`? If he's getting empty lists, `[]` tests to `False`, so just do `[line for line in csv.reader(data.split("\n")) if line]`

Comment: @adsmith because I overlooked something ;-)

Comment: or I did -- upon a re-read, it looks like OP may be looking for only rows that contain more than one column.

Comment: OP specifically requested [['a' , 1],['b' , 2]...] as output

Comment: @Totem I see your point, added that to my answer in any case ;-)

Comment: @janos I think it was just an oversight on OP part and he wants the [str, str] :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> data ="\n random stuff\n a,1\n b,2\n c,3\n ... "
>>> [line.split(',') for line in data.split('\n') if ',' in line]
[[' a', '1'], [' b', '2'], [' c', '3']]
```

Basically, you split on `\n`, ignore every line without comma with the `if` condition, and then split every result by the comma found.

Comment: Keep in mind though that you're replacing the `csv.reader` in the OP with its quick-and-dirty version = `line.split(',')`

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are either testing `len(line)` unnecessarily, or testing `',' in line` unnecessarily.

This is the shortest solution:

```
[line for line in csv.reader(data.split("\n")) if line]
```

Although if you want only the elements with more than one element in them, `',' in line` is a decent way to do that.